# Silently updating a device in Single App Mode using WSO2

Tags: wso2, mdm

Would it be possible to use WSO2 to put an iPad in Single App Mode and then also silently update that App silently remotely without going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now WSO2 EMM doesn't support single app mode. This is a feature which will be offered in the next release. Anyway since its free open source you may incorporate that feature by extending the libraries.

Comment: Thanks for that, how does this relate to my second question, updating that App silently. We can wait a little longer and are new to iOS MDM, so it's better for us to wait for it to be in the release.

Comment: WSO2 EMM provide a MAM (mobile application management) component inbuilt. This is basically a sort of private app store where you can have this deployed on your enterprise. There is a publisher component written which does the app creation, update same as you do in app store or google play submission. This way you can create and install apps in your employees phones. Yes this is silent. :)